# syntax error at or near "ON" django postgress

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am doing a Many to Many relationship. But when adding values to that field I get an error.

```
class pA(models.Model):
    hu = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")

class pB(models.Model):
    jo = models.ManyToManyField(pA)
```

This is the error I get when adding a value to pB:

```
error de sintaxis en o cerca de «ON»
LINE 1: ...dule_main_pb_jo" ("pb_id", "pa_id") VALUES (2, 1) ON CONFLIC...
                                                             ^
```

This error appears only when I use a postgres DB, but not SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The Postgre version must be updated. I was using version 9.4 and upgraded to version 13.

Comment: This is a workaround, not the solution. And the minimum version you need to upgrade to is [9,5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)